# What piano piece is this?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music, piano

https://youtu.be/Q21DmLCluhs this is a video I took of someone playing this song and I really want to know what it is so I can learn it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the link is broken and the poster never came back to approve an answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is [Ludovico Einaudi - Divenire](https://youtu.be/9qvglWAHDak?t=2m), the quoted part starts around 2:00.

A friend of mine plays this song.  The original is much faster than the recording you supplied.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite certain it's Rob Costlow.

Here is a playlist with the song I think it might be.

They are quite similar so I suggest checking the others as well.

Here is another playlist of the same with another match.